# Angular2 image crop and zoom

Tags: image-processing, angular

I am looking for a Angular2 image cropper/zoomer library.  I found ng2-img-cropper is useful for doing cropping; but I also need the ability to pan and zoom.  Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Joining the question...

Comment: *Does anyone have any recommendations?* No, but I'm guessing Google would.

Comment: You can try [Croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/). There is also Angular 2 wrapper around the Croppie library called [ngx-croppie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-croppie), but it not allows you to get for example coordinates of crop box. Because I need these coordinates, I created simple "Hello Angular Croppie" project, which you can find [here](https://github.com/milanhlinak/hello-angular-croppie).

And downvoters of my answer below can also provide some great tips instead of downvoting...